# Docker mounted volumes remains sometimes empty

Tags: windows, docker, wsl-2

Perhaps I'm missing something stupid but there is something I don't understand.

If I do  `docker run -d --name test -v ~/test-log:/var/log/nginx -v ~/test-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d nginx:latest`

I've got

```
ls -l ~/test-log
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep  1 11:17 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep  1 11:17 error.log
```

But

```
ls -l ~/test-config
total 0
```

However without any mounts `/etc/nginx/conf.d` is not empty

```
docker run --rm --name test2  nginx:latest ls -l /etc/nginx/conf.d
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1093 Aug 11 14:50 default.conf
```

So why files in `/var/log/nginx` are well present in `~/test-log` while `~/test-config` remains empty and moreover `/etc/nginx/conf.d` becomes empty ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: When you run `docker run --rm --name test2  nginx:latest ls -l /etc/nginx/conf.d` this creates a new container which does not have your `-v` mounts. So they won't turn up there. 

Try `docker run -it --name test -v ~/test-log:/var/log/nginx -v ~/test-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d --entrypoint bash nginx:latest`...

Now investigate inside the container while its running

Comment: Ok, I known it.  it was just a way to "prove" that without any mounts /etc/nginx/conf.d is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes mount files/directories from the source over whatever exists inside the image at that location. You no longer see the image contents when a mount replaces access to that directory, same a mounting a filesystem other ways in Linux.

Named volumes in Linux are a semi exception because docker initializes the contents of a named volume with the image directory contents. This does not apply to host volumes like you are using.

Once the volume is mounted, files are created/modified/deleted by the application running inside the container. In this case, that app creates logs, but it does not write it's own configuration files.

Comment: Your 3rd explanation convinced me.  Now I understand.  Thx.